# Joomla DB where statement not works as expected

Tags: module, database, jdatabase, select

I don't understand the world right now. I try to make a simple query from the DB, but it fails with the message that the column is not known. I do not understand why Joomla! tries to see the value I am looking for as a column. This is my query:

```
            $data = new stdClass();
        try{
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query
                ->select('*')
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__extensions'));
                $query->where($db->quoteName('element') . " = " . $db->quoteName('com_componentname'));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $data->params = $db->loadObject();


        }catch(Exception $e){
            $data->query = $query->dump();
            $data->errormsg = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $data;

    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

The response is:

```
'errormsg' => 'Unknown column \'com_componentname\' in \'where clause\'',
```

Why does Joomla! try to find the component name as a column? What I want:
Where *componentname* in Columns *name* from table *extensions*.

Or is there another / better way to load the parameters of a component within a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JDatabaseDriver::quoteName()`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_quoteName) is for quoting SQL identifiers. Use [`JDatabaseDriver:quote()`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_quote) to quote and escape strings.

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('element') . ' = ' . $db->quote('com_componentname'));
```

Comment: unbelivable - thank you... did you know also why it had not worked like so: $query->where('element = com_componentname') ? it throws the same error...

Comment: Because `com_componentname` must be quoted.